# using qwt in QT Creator gives error Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: qt-creator, qwt

Starting: C:/Qt/2010.02.1/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -w 
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qwt/qwt-5.2.1/textengines/data_plot'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory`C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qwt/qwt-5.2.1/textengines/data_plot'
linking ....\examples\bin\data_plot.exe
c:/qt/2010.02.1/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqwt5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qwt/qwt-5.2.1/textengines/data_plot'
mingw32-make: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qwt/qwt-5.2.1/textengines/data_plot'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [....\examples\bin\data_plot.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project data_plot
When executing build step 'Make'

What might be the reason of such an error??

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the qwt5 library was not found.

Check that your QWT library is indeed called qwt5.dll and that the linker is given the path to find that library (Check that there is a line reading LIBS += -L/path/to/qwt -lqwt5 in your .pro file).